# Why does creating a new File thows an Exception?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-file

I want to take a picture with the Camera, what I want to save in a specific format (date.jpg)

Here is my code:

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
     File photoFile = null;
     try {
         photoFile = createFile();
         photoPath = photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
     } catch (IOException ex) {
         Log.i(SelfieConstantUtility.TAG, "IOException with creating file");
     }
     if (photoFile != null) {
        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent,SelfieConstantUtility.REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
     }
}

private File createFile() throws IOException{
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat(SelfieConstantUtility.DATEFORMAT).format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

    File image = new File(timeStamp+".jpg");
    image.createNewFile();
    return image;
}
```

This is my Android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".DailySelfieActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**Why isn't the file created?**
I think the problem is here, but I don't know what:

```
image.createNewFile();
```

Comment: Which exception? Post the logcat output please.

Comment: 11-25 15:37:02.574      786-786/com.gaborcsikos.weebly.dailyselfie I/DailySelfie﹕ IOException with creating file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are using constructor

```
new File(String path)
```

timestamp+".jpg" isn't path I think... check this out:

```
new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                      .getAbsolutePath(), timestamp+".jpg");
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the problem.